# Is it possible for EF Core to respect code in OnModelCreating/ConfigureConventions as part of migration code generation?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I don't know if I'm expecting too much, but there have been a few different things I've ran into where I attempted to configure EF Core 6 behavior in `OnModelCreating` and/or `ConfigureConventions` that simply don't seem to be respected when new migrations are created.

For example, I would like to force all string properties to be `varchar` (instead of `nvarchar`). There are dozens of examples of handling this via model property attributes that *do* seem to be respected at migration code generation time, but unfortunately they are all at the property level. I have also seen examples setting `IsUnicode(false)` via overriding `ConfigureConventions` like so:

```
protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
{
    configurationBuilder
        .DefaultTypeMapping<string>()
        .HasColumnType("varchar")
        .IsUnicode(false);
}
```

But this code doesn't seem to be respected at migration code generation time. It's simply ignored. I realize it will be respected at runtime when queries are being generated, but I'm specifically talking about during development when generating new migration code.

Should this code in `ConfigureConventions` be respected when new migration code is created such that if I add a new string property to the model and then add a new migration, that the generated code should show the new column type as `varchar`?

**UPDATE per @David Brown's request for repro example:**

I created a new .NET6 Core Console app with the following:

**Program.cs**

```
using ConsoleApp1;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

IHost host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**MyDbContext.cs**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WorkRequest> WorkRequests { get; set; }

        protected override void ConfigureConventions(ModelConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder)
        {
            configurationBuilder
                .DefaultTypeMapping<string>()
                .HasColumnType("varchar")
                .IsUnicode(false);

            base.ConfigureConventions(configurationBuilder);
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

**WorkRequest.cs**

```
namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class WorkRequest
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }

        //[Unicode(false), MaxLength(256)]  
        public string SubmitterId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ConsoleApp1.csproj**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="6.0.8" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Migrations\" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I then simply drop to the Package Manager Console and enter:

```
add-migration InitialCreate -verbose
```

The resulting migration code always shows SubmitterId as nvarchar(max) unless I use the commented property attribute instead of the ConfigureConventions code:

```
SubmitterId = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(max)", nullable: false),
```

Comment: Yes.  Model configuration should be reflected in your migrations.  Can you simplify this to a minimal repro and post that?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - updated with full code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in `OnModelCreating` / `ConfigureConventions` is of course respected in migrations.

The problem you are hitting is the [`DefaultTypeMapping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelconfigurationbuilder.defaulttypemapping?view=efcore-6.0) method, specifically the difference between expectations and what it really does.

Just looking at the method name, one would expect exactly what you did - that it specifies the default mapping for a CLR type. From the other side, there is another method called [`Properties`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelconfigurationbuilder.properties?view=efcore-6.0) which returns a builder with similar methods (just starting with `Are` / `Have` instead of `Is` / `Has`), so it's unclear what's the difference and which one you should use.

The documentation of `DefaultTypeMapping` does not help a lot:

> Marks the given type as a scalar, even when used outside of entity types. This allows values of this type to be used in queries that are not referencing property of this type.
>
> Unlike `Properties(Type)` this method should only be called on a non-nullable concrete type. Calling it on a base type will not apply the configuration to the derived types.
>
> Calling this is rarely needed. If there are properties of the given type calling `Properties(Type)` should be enough in most cases.

It shows a small difference in the behavior and says that using the method is rarely needed, but does not say why.

[Default type mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/bulk-configuration#default-type-mapping) section of the docs is a bit cleaner:

> Generally, EF is able to translate queries with constants of a type that is not supported by the provider, as long as you have specified a value converter for a property of this type. However, in queries that don't involve any properties of this type, there is no way for EF to find the correct value converter. In this case, it's possible to call `DefaultTypeMapping` to add or override a provider type mapping

So, it turns out this method and the associated fluent configuration calls affect only *query translation*, and not the entity property mappings (thus migrations).

Shortly, inside `ConfigureConventions` use `Properties` method and fluent API for configuring the model defaults, and they will be respected everywhere, including migrations, e.g. in your example:

```cs
configurationBuilder
    .Properties<string>()
    //.HaveColumnType("varchar") // not needed, see below
    .AreUnicode(false); // abstract way of specifying varchar vs nvarchar
```

---

As a side note, be also aware of the following little note in the docs

> Data annotations do not override pre-convention configuration.

which means that if you use data annotations (attributes) for non default columns of the type configured via `Properties`, they won't be respected (you have to use fluent API and `OnModelCreating`). This is quite important difference from "default" EF Core conventions which have less priority than data annotations, and just another example of poorly documented poor design decision (they say, for me it is implementation bug) difference between logical expectation (we are only overriding default conventions, right?) and the actual behavior.

Comment: You sir, are "the man".  :)   This was driving me crazy.  Thank you!!